# HTML & CSS - How to place DIVs next to each other on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a chat interface, and my task is now to add a date between messages. The date must be centered, and messages must be traditionally on the left and right.

Messages are working correctly, but dates are a problem.

How it looks:

[image]

Chat is divided by sections. Each section has a date. Each section can have multiply messages.

Code of section is following:

```
        <div>
            <div class="discussionMessageDate">{date here}</div>
            <ul className="noDot">
                <li className="noDot + ..logic to figure out if to apple 'right' class"><span class="discussionMessage">{message}</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

classes are

```
.discussionMessage {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px 13px;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: 300px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.discussionMessageDate {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px 13px;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: block
}

.noDot {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.right {
   float: right;
  clear: both;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific as to what behavior you are seeing which is incorrect? How are the dates a "problem"?

Comment: Have you tried declaring `text-align: center` on `.discussionMessageDate`?

Comment: incorrect behaviour is that dates are out of list. order must be date->message->message->date->message->date->message .<..> - each date must be shown in list. but list of dates shows in different place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added a clearfix to the wrapping div, this looks like i think it should work

https://jsfiddle.net/hmtkyz96/

```
<div class="discussionMessageContainer">
  <div class="discussionMessageDate">{date here}</div>
  <ul class="noDot">
    <li class="right"><span class="discussionMessage">{message}</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

.discussionMessageContainer::after {
  content:'';
  clear:both;
  display:table;
}
```

Comment: now order is fine! how can I align "discussionMessageDate" in center of container and save alignment of li items?

Answer (score 1):

You shoud add the "text-align: center;" property to your "discussionMessageDate" class, in order to center the text. A div displays its content aligned to the left, by default.

Also, I imagine you need to specify the max size of the container also, to 300px, otherwise, your list will spread across your screen, meanwhile, your date has a fixed size.

And you need to clear your float, because otherwise the parent of the floated element loses its height.

Like this:

```
body{
    max-width: 300px;
}
.discussionMessageDate {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 13px;
    max-width: 300px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.clearer{
    clear: both;
}

<div>
    <div class="discussionMessageDate">{date here}</div>
        <ul class="noDot">
            <li class="right"><span class="discussionMessage">{message}</span></li>
            <li class=""><span class="discussionMessage">{message}</span></li>
            <li class="right"><span class="discussionMessage">{message}</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
    <div>
        <div class="discussionMessageDate">{date here}</div>
            <ul class="noDot">
                <li class="noDot + ..logic to figure out if to apple 'right' class"><span class="discussionMessage">{message}</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is this answer??

Comment: This should be in comments, not as an answer

Comment: Well, tell that to StackOverflow... you cannot write comments with less than 50 reputation. So please don't downvote just because that is how the site works...

Comment: On the contrary, I should downvote just because this is how the site works. You'd better edit your 'answer' and give a proper code example without asking any questions. Then I will undo my downvote and if your answer is good I will upvote

Comment: Don't take it personally.   Your response doesn't have an example or explanation.

Comment: Don't take it personally.   Your response doesn't have an example or explanation.

Comment: I don't take it personally at all. Thank you, I actually appreciate feedback that helps improve my contributions. Just a downvote doesn't really say what you did wrong, but a comment does (when you can add it :) )

Comment: Well, we all started like this:)